# C# Sending .wav file using WebSocket returns OperationAborted

Tags: javascript, node.js, c#, unity-game-engine, websocket

So I have a local Node.js server and a C# client inside a Unity project, what I am trying to do is to stream a .wav file to the server in the same machine (localhost:3000) using WebSockets but the error I get is a pretty vague OperationAborted error, it doesn't tell me if there is a type mismatch between the client and server or other thing I need to get fixed.

**C# Client**

```
public class WebSocketController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource microphoneSource;

    private void Start()
    {
        string url = "ws://localhost";
        int port = 3000;
        string filePath = "C:/Users/eduar/AppData/LocalLow/Richard J/Sound Recorder/Audio_2023_04_05_23_47_56_2845.wav";
        const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;
        byte[] requestBytes = ConvertWAVtoByteArray(filePath, microphoneSource, HEADER_SIZE);
        SendHttpRequest(url, filePath, port, requestBytes);
    }

    public string SendHttpRequest(string url, string filePath, int port, byte[] requestBytes)
    {
        string _responseMessage = null;
        Socket _socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        using (_socket)
        {
            // Create and try to connect a dual-stack socket.
            try
            {
                // Create and connect a dual-stack socket.
                Debug.Log("Connecting to server.");
                _socket.Connect(new Uri(url).Host, port);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Could not connect to server: " + e.Message);
            }

            // Create the preBuffer data.
            byte[] preBuf = requestBytes;

            // Create the postBuffer data.
            byte[] postBuf = requestBytes;

            // Try to send the request.
            try
            {
                //Send file to the remote device.
                Debug.Log($"Sending {filePath} with buffers to the host.");

                SocketAsyncEventArgs _socketArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                _socketArgs.SetBuffer(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
                _socketArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(SendCallback);
                _socket.SendAsync(_socketArgs);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Could not send http request: " + e.Message + "\n");
            }
            finally 
            {
                // Release the socket.
                _socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                _socket.Close();
            }
        }

        Debug.Log("Http response: " + _responseMessage);
        return _responseMessage;
    }

    private void SendCallback(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {
            // To stream ou may need to specify some type of state and pass it into the SendHttpRequest method so you don't start sending from scratch again untill whole file is sent
            Debug.Log("Socket could send file sucessfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Socket error: " + e.SocketError);
        }
    }

    private byte[] ConvertWAVtoByteArray(string filePath, AudioSource audioSource, int headerSize)
    {
        //Open the stream and read it back.
        byte[] bytes = new byte[audioSource.clip.samples + headerSize];
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            fs.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript Server**

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server,{maxHttpBufferSize: 1e7})

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("headers at connection:")
  console.log(socket.handshake.headers)
  socket.on('audio', async function (msg) {
      console.log("headers on evnt:")
      console.log(socket.handshake.headers)
      var date = new Date(msg.timeMillis);
      await fs.promises.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "videos", `${date.toString()}.wav`), msg.data, "binary");         
  });
});

server.listen(3000)
console.log("Running on port: "+3000)
```

Comment: I get no errors on the server side. Only OperationAborted on the client side.

Comment: I already opened my firewall doors for the port 3000.

Comment: You are, in fact, not using WebSockets to send the file. // Programming questions are mostly off-topic on Super User. Instead, they belong on [so]. Make sure you follow the guidelines over there!

Comment: Try moving the shutdown and close it reads as if you say send and before it finishes to runs the shutdown